# Loop with if inside for 2 threads

Tags: java

I'm having trouble getting the output I want. Therefore, these are two threads running in the critical section. One of the threads prints "a" and the other prints "b". The threads have to print until 30 chars. After that, the thread printing next should print a new line and reset
the character counter to 1. I can get get them printed, but I couldn't find a way to print the last char (31) and reset the counter to 1 and break the loop and exit.

My program is running until you force it to stop because I'm setting the loop to the start point. 
I know that I could've gotten it by setting do -while (counter <=30), but I want it to be first set to while (true)
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need two separate classes (which extend Thread) that do the same thing (I know right now there's a slight difference but it's unnecessary).  You can simply do

```
Thread a = new MyThread().start();
Thread b = new MyThread().start();
```

Second what you want is for your two threads to **synchronize** on the number of characters.  What you have currently is a classic race condition, and you need to protect the code in your critical section. To do this you need a synchronization object. Let's say that what you do is you create an object O and pass it to each of the threads

```
Object lock = new Object();
Thread a = new MyThread(lock).start();
Thread b = new MyThread(lock).start();
```

And you save that as a member variable

```
public MyThread(Object lock) {
   this.lock = lock;
}
```

Now you use this lock to synchronize when accessing the shared resource *counter*.  It's very important that both threads have the same lock.

```
int myCounter;
sychronized (lock) {
    if (counter == 30) counter = 0;
    else { counter++ }
    myCounter = counter; // Make a copy of the shared counter and release the lock
}
// Code to print 'A'+myCounter, or whatrever you want with myCounter. This is your local copy and should be used here
```

Answer (score 0):

You need your shared variables to be `volatile` so they are not cached by each thread.

Also, since you cannot make an array of volatile values, use two booleans:

```
volatile int turn;
volatile boolean flag1 = false;
volatile boolean flag2 = false;
volatile int counter = 0;
volatile String cscVar = "a";
volatile String cscVar2 = "b";
```

To learn more about `volatile` and atomic access: [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html)